# How to add custom methods to custom constructors in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, constructor

I am new to javascript and I have a lot of questions. I came to know about a javascript library called VueJS and it's really awesome. Here is an example :

HTML :

```
 <h1 id="test">{{ test }}, I like Javascript</h1>
```

JS :

```
 var vue = new Vue({
   el: "#test",
   data: {
      test: "Yes"
   }
 });
 return vue;
```

Output :

```
 Yes, I like javascript
```

I was really amazed looking at it's syntax structure. Then I thought, can I make such ? But since I am less experienced I can't ? So, I want a help ? Let's assume a very basic one :

HTML :

```
  <h1 id="test"></h1>
```

JS :

```
  var my = new MyCustomOne({
    el: "#test",
    html: "Hello Everyone",
    css: {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "#008eff"
    }
   });
```

I don't want to import that nearly 100KB library for just using few functions, and by the way I also want to make my own. So please can you help me to create the MyCustomOne() constructor with the above given methods ? Thanks In Advace.

Comment: What help do you need? We certainly won't write that function for you. Have you tried anything? Start small!

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you said right but I need a little guidance to start that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a quite good solution to that. So, here is a piece of code :

```
 function MyCustomOne(stock) {
   var sel = document.querySelectorAll(stock.el); // Selecting all matching elements in your selector method
   for( var i = 0; i < sel.length; ++i ) {
     sel[i].innerHTML += stock.html; // Setting the text 
     sel[i].style.cssText = stock.style; // Setting css properties with values
     sel[i].style[stock.css.prop] = stock.css.val; // You can also nest them
   };
 };
```

You can use it as :

```
 var my = new MyCustomOne({
   el: ".demo",
   html: "Hello World !",
   style: "background : blue",
   css: {
      prop: "color",
      val: "white",
   }
  });
```

But till, I prefer you to learn JavaScript first, befor moving to any javascript library / framework as VueJS.

Comment: @Arcnadian Arc Thank You, and yes I shall learn javascript.....

Answer (score 0):

I think for a beginner it is not so easy to build your own version of Vue, because this function actually is big. I found for you some repositories which will help you to understand implementation of vue core:

- [tiny-vue](https://github.com/lihongxun945/tiny-vue/tree/master/src)
- [another-tiny-vue](https://github.com/xiaofuzi/deep-in-vue/blob/master/src/the-super-tiny-vue.js)
- [build-your-own-vuejs](https://github.com/jsrebuild/build-your-own-vuejs)
- [read-vue-source-code](https://github.com/numbbbbb/read-vue-source-code)

But If your purpose just to find simpler and lighter alternative of vue, I would recommend you to try [Mithril (9.5kb) framework](https://mithril.js.org/)